# Click event not posting to handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm playing with JQuery, and I'm trying to fire a `Click` event on a button, to run off to a handler in my asp.net application, and getting some strange results.

I'll post the code and then explain whats happening :-

```
 $(function () {

            $("[id$='btnClaimValidate']").click(callSwapClaimHandler);

            function callSwapClaimHandler() {


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/handlers/investor-tickets/claimswapvalidator.ashx",
                    data: {
                        investorId: $("[id$='hdnInvestor']").val(),
                        investorTicketId: $("[id$='hdnInvestorTicket']").val(),
                        originalClaimId: $("[id$='hdnInvestorTicketClaimId']").val(),
                        newClaimId: $("[id$='txtClaim']").val()

                    },

                    dataType: "html",
                    error: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    },
                    success:

                        function (data) {

                            var $newdiv = data;
                            $("[id$='divMessageData']").append($newdiv);
                        }

                });
            }

        });
```

With the code above, the handler is never called. The event is 100% being fired on click. I've tested by removing the ajax post function, and replaced it with a simple `alert("Hello);` command to be sure.

What is strange is that if i register the click event to actually execute on DOM load by doing this :-

```
$("[id$='btnClaimValidate']").click(callSwapClaimHandler());
```

The handler is fired as the page loads and then works as expected.

By taking off the parenthesis, so that it is only fired on click, the post never actually executes.

I've debugged the browser session, and the function runs, but it never gets to the handler, and no content is returned.

Can anyone explain what's going wrong?

Comment: Try doing it without data,  if it is called then you need to stringify your data parameters.

Comment: I did this to test if it was firing,im aware of that

Comment: The data parameters work fine, i'm able to catch the all in the handler, when i call the function on load (as a test). Its just not getting to the handler, when the click event is fired.

Comment: Your code is written as if there is only one of each element. Why are you using `id ends-with` selectors?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the HTML page is a simple Div with an id, like i say, it grabs the response perfectly fine when its fired on page load.

Comment: I need to see if the `btnClaimValidate` is within the div or not. please just supply a sample (preferably saved from the browser and not source)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie becuaeit wasnt able to locate the elements without it, the asp.net adds a unique part to the clientid in the html.

Comment: You comment to `Scarface Ron` gave me the clue. Your page is refreshing immediately as it is a `submit` button! If only you have provided the HTML earlier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment to `@Scarface Ron` is the clue. Your page is refreshing as the default button behavior was not stopped. Also just use the function inline in the handler:

```
$(function () {

    $("[id$='btnClaimValidate']").click(function (e) {
        // Stop the button actioning!
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/handlers/investor-tickets/claimswapvalidator.ashx",
            data: {
                investorId: $("[id$='hdnInvestor']").val(),
                investorTicketId: $("[id$='hdnInvestorTicket']").val(),
                originalClaimId: $("[id$='hdnInvestorTicketClaimId']").val(),
                newClaimId: $("[id$='txtClaim']").val()

            },

            dataType: "html",
            error: function () {
                alert("failure");
            },
            success:

            function (data) {

                var $newdiv = data;
                $("[id$='divMessageData']").append($newdiv);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

*apologies if I got the closing braces wrong here*

Comment: @Derek: Next time someone asks for the HTML too... please provide it. It would have been obvious then :)

Comment: I see what you mean now, apologies.

Answer (score -1):

The simple explanation here is that your button selector - `[id$='btnClaimValidate']` - isn't matching anything at the time it is executed. Hard to say why (you're generating that part of the DOM after the page is loaded? You have a typo?) but you can test this easily enough:

```
$(function()
{
  alert($("[id$='btnClaimValidate']").length);
});
```

If the value is 0, then this is your problem and you'll have a specific area to investigate further.

Alternately, use your browser's DOM inspector to verify that an event has actually been attached to the button after the load has completed.

If the problem is simply that the button is added to the DOM *after* the page is loaded, then you might want to consider using a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of attaching the handler directly to the button. For instance:

```
$("document").on("click", "[id$='btnClaimValidate']", callSwapClaimHandler);
```

This will attach the event to the document (which exists) but mandate that the handler is only called when the event has bubbled up from the button (which may not exist yet when the handler is bound, but probably will later).

Comment: there is 100% an event been attached to the button my friend. as i mentioned, i swapped out the body of the function with a simple alert function to test it was firing, and it worked fine. for whatever reason on click, although the function runs, as ive debugged it in the browser, it does'nt reach the handler

Comment: i did as you said, it returned 1.

Comment: Note: Never use `body` for delegated event handlers. It has a nasty bug related to styling that can stop it working at all. Use `document` as the default if nothing is closer.

Comment: If you've replaced the body of the handler with `alert(...)` and that executes, then it *is* reaching the handler - but your handler isn't doing what you expect it to. Debug this a bit further: put an alert() in the success function and see if it gets that far.

Comment: Interesting, @TrueBlueAussie - I was unaware of this. Got any references for that bug?

Comment: Found it myself ages ago. It is pretty simple to repro. Use absolutely positioned children under body (or any other styling that results in a calculated `body` height of 0) and mouse events will not bubble to body :)

Comment: Interesting, i have changedmy code to $("document").on("click", "[id$='btnClaimValidate']", callSwapClaimHandler); and now the "faiure" alert is flashing up and disapearing itself?

Comment: Excellent! Now you just have to figure out why your POST request is failing, @Derek.

Comment: Ive removed everything but the url & type, and it still does it. My mind is boggled, as it works fine when you call the "Post" on DOM Load.. why would that work! its bizarre!